# Various proofs of Cantor's theorem.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I am the kind of person who is interested in various proofs of some theorems. And so I have a question: what proofs are there for the fact that a set has a smaller cardinal than the set of its subsets (Cantor's Theorem). There is a classic proof using the diagonal argument, but is there any other proof?

Comment: It’s not a diagonalization argument.

Comment: In the general case it's not really a diagonalization argument, though it is sort of a generalization of that concept.

Comment: Yes, this is a small generalization, but still?

Comment: Although Cantor's Theorem does not use the [Diagonal Lemma from Mathematical Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma), it does use an argument which is commonly known as a "diagonal argument"; see e.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_argument), which points to Cantor's Theorem and Russell's Paradox, as well as the Diagonal Lemma.

Comment: There is a completely different proof of the uncountability of the real numbers ([Cantor's first proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_first_set_theory_article#Second_theorem)), but I am not aware of any other proof of the general Cantor Theorem.